# Spatial Query Tool in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

I'm relatively new to using QGIS and GIS platforms in general.

I'm following a guided exercise in QGIS and need to use the 'Spatial Query Tool', however I can't seem to find it anywhere in QGIS 3.4.

Comment: To what ends shall you use the tool?

Comment: It's integrated into processing and isn't a plugin anymore. Search the processing tool box for it. Couldn't find the question this is a duplicate for.

Answer (score 3):

Well i think the equivalent is to be found here from now on :

**Vector / Research Tools / select by location**